# please tell me how to write this equation in Align, I tried coding below but got errors

Tags: errors, coding

```
\begin{align*}
c\sup_{L>0,L\in \mathbb{Z}}\biggl[ \biggl{ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}2^{(k \alpha_1(0) -L \lambda) q_1(0)}biggl ( \sum_{i=k-5}^{+\infty} \lambda_i \norm{a_i}_{p_1(\cdot)} \biggr )^{q_1(0)} \biggr}^{1/q_1(0)}\\+
biggl{ \sum_{k=0}^{L}2^{(k \alpha_1(0) -L \lambda) q_1(\infty)}\biggl ( \sum_{i=k-5}^{+\infty} \lambda_i \norm{a_i}_{p_1(\cdot)} \biggr )^{q_1(\infty)} \biggr}^{1/q_1(\infty)} \biggr]
\end{align*}
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please make yourself also familiar with the StackExchange editor, so your quistion will be readable and make a question out of it with an appropriate header.

Comment: `\biggl\{`, not `\biggl{` (and likewise for `}`).

Answer (score 6):

I think a simple `multline*` would be as nice and simpler  to type. Here is an example, with some cosmetic spacing changes (exponents, line spacing and delimiter sizes):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}\lVert\rVert

\begin{document}

    \begin{multline*}
        c \sup_{\substack{L>0\\L\in \mathbb{Z}}}
         \Biggl[%
           \biggl\{
                \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}\!\!2^{(k \alpha_1(0) -L \lambda) q_1(0)}
                \biggl(
                    \sum_{i=k-5}^{+\infty} \lambda_i \norm{a_i}_{p_1(\cdot)}
                \biggr)^{\!\!q_1(0)}
            \biggr\}^{\!\!1/q_1(0)}\\[-1.5ex]
           {}+
           \biggl\{
                \sum_{k=0}^{L}2^{(k \alpha_1(0) -L \lambda) q_1(\infty)}
                \biggl(
                    \sum_{i=k-5}^{+\infty} \lambda_i \norm{a_i}_{p_1(\cdot)}
                \biggr)^{\!\!q_1(\infty)}
            \biggr\}^{\negthickspace1/q_1(\infty)}
        \Biggr]
    \end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Most importantly, you need to be aware that in order to typeset curly braces -- `{` and `}` -- in a (La)TeX document, they must be entered as `\{` and `\}`. Thus, replaced both instances of `\biggl{` and `\biggr}` with `\biggl\{` and `\biggr\}`, respectively.

You're currently not making use of most of the machinery of the `align*` environment. I suggest you use a nested `equation*/aligned` pair of environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
\sup_{L>0,L\in \mathbb{Z}}\Biggl[ 
\biggl\{ \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}} 2^{(k \alpha_1(0) -L \lambda) q_1(0)}
&\biggl(\, \sum_{i=k-5}^{+\infty} \lambda_i \norm{a_i}_{p_1(\cdot)} 
  \!\biggr )^{\!q_1(0)} \biggr\}^{\!1/q_1(0)}\\
{}+\biggl\{ \sum_{k=0}^{L}2^{(k \alpha_1(0) -L \lambda) q_1(\infty)}
&\biggl(\, \sum_{i=k-5}^{+\infty} \lambda_i \norm{a_i}_{p_1(\cdot)} 
  \!\biggr )^{\!q_1(\infty)} \biggr\}^{\!1/q_1(\infty)}\, \Biggr]
\end{split}\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks dear, What is the role of  smashoperator?

Comment: @ShoaibAssar - `\smashoperator` is a macro provided by the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package. If you look at the output produced by `\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}}`, you'll notice that there is no gap between the summation symbol and the subsequent material (which starts with `2^{k...}`. Using `\smashoperator` lets you display the formula more compactly.

Comment: ok got it thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you wanted?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,commath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        c \sup\limits_{L>0,L\in \mathbb{Z}}
        \biggl[%
            \biggl\{
                \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}2^{(k \alpha_1(0) -L \lambda) q_1(0)}
                \biggl(
                    \sum_{i=k-5}^{+\infty} \lambda_i \norm{a_i}_{p_1(\cdot)}
                \biggr)^{q_1(0)}
            \biggr\}^{1/q_1(0)}\\+
            \biggl\{
                \sum_{k=0}^{L}2^{(k \alpha_1(0) -L \lambda) q_1(\infty)}
                \biggl(
                    \sum_{i=k-5}^{+\infty} \lambda_i \norm{a_i}_{p_1(\cdot)}
                \biggr)^{q_1(\infty)}
            \biggr\}^{1/q_1(\infty)}
        \biggr]
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Sorry for the overkill indentation of the code, but it helped the troubleshooting.

Please note the loaded packages. I don't know which ones have you loaded; they are my best guess, since your code snippet is not a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: thanks for kind information