# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{split} error appears in coding below

Tags: errors

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
c\sup_{L>0,L\in \mathbb{Z}}\Biggl[ 
\biggl\{ \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}}
& \biggl(\, \sum_{i=k-5}^{+\infty} \lambda_i 2^{(k-i)\alpha_1(0)-L\lambda} 
\!\biggr )^{\!q_1(0)} \biggr\}^{\!1/q_1(0)}\\
{}+\biggl\{ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}
& \biggl(\, \sum_{i=0}^{+iggr\}^{\!1/q_1(0)}\,+\biggl\{ \sum_{k=0}^{L}
& \biggl(\, \sum_{i=k-5}\infty} \lambda_i 2^{(k-i)\alpha^-_1-L\lambda} 
\!\biggr )^{\!q_1(0)} \b^{+\infty} \lambda_i 2^{(k-i)(\alpha_1)_\infty-L\lambda} 
\!\biggr )^{\!q_1(\infty)} \biggr\}^{\!1/q_1(\infty)}\, \Biggr]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Could you start by incorporating what you've learned from your [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/539825/107497)?  Specifically, `{` should be `\{`, `}` should be `\}`, you need to include `\documentclass{???} \begin{document} ... \end{document}` and any other relevant packages, and you need to format your code (highlight and click `{}`) so that it's readable.

Comment: The `split` environment supports only one alignment point, and the second line that begins `& \biggl(` isn't ended by `\\ ` before another `&`.  If you need more than one alignment point, the `alignedat` environment is a better choice (than `aligned`) when extra space isn't wanted between segments.  Details can be found in the `amsmath` users guide.  (`texdoc amsldoc`)

Comment: The fragment `\sum_{i=0}^{+iggr\}` cannot possibly be correct. I have no idea what you're trying to express here; maybe something got deleted by accident?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the main issue appears to be driven by an unresolvable typo.

Comment: also lot of closed parenthesis, brackets etc are missed.